# Unable to retrieve version information from OpenGL 3.2 / 3.3

Tags: c, opengl, opengl-3

I've followed the basic instructions here:

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.1_The_First_Triangle_%28C%2B%2B/Win%29#Rendering_Context_Creation

The only thing I've tweaked is the creation of the context to be 3.2 or 3.3:

```
const int attributes[] =
{
    WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
    WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2,
    WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
    0
};
```

And then after the creation of the context (which returns TRUE for success) I check the version with:

```
// Double check the version (old way)
const GLubyte *const pszGLVersion = glGetString(GL_VERSION);

// Double check the version (new way)
GLint glVersion[2];
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &glVersion[0]);
glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &glVersion[1]);
```

However, pszGLVersion is NULL, and glVersion[0] and glVersion[1] are both left uninitialised!

Why does the creation of an OpenGL 3.2 & 3.3 context succeed, but then fail to get version information?

Comment: context creation does not return a boolean. It returns a context handle. Are you sure it succeeded ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it succeeded, an HGLRC structure is successfully returned from the call.

Comment: Is the context also activated? Creating a context doesn't automatically acticate it → wglMakeCurrent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason I can't get the version information out is because my graphics card doesn't support 3.2 or 3.3.

Answer (score 2):

Did you make the context current?  You'll note that `glGetString` doesn't take a context parameter, it works on the current context.  You can't use it until after you call `wglMakeCurrent`, a newly created context is not made current by default.

Comment: Hi Ben, yes my code is nearly identical to the example in the URL. I create an OpenGL 2.1 context, then use that to create an OpenGL 3.2 or 3.3 context. FYI, OpenGL 3.1 returns valid version info.